# Use T-SQL to Get/Set Server Backup Locations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find a way to use T-SQL to get and set the DB Server's (or named instance's) backup location. This would be equivalent to using SSMS to right-click the instance name --> Properties --> Database Settings.

I've found that you can use master.dbo.xp_instance_regread to query the current location from the registry; is this the best way and how can one update this location?

Thank you.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way of doing this without using `dbo.xp_instance_regread`. See some discussion [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1319398-1550-1.aspx). If you profile what SSMS does, it also uses it.

Answer (score 0):

See if this gets what you need:

```
SELECT physical_device_name, sd.name 
   FROM msdb..backupmediafamily bmf 
   INNER JOIN msdb..backupset bms ON bmf.media_set_id = bms.media_set_id 
   INNER JOIN master..sysdatabases sd ON bms.database_name = sd.name 
   AND bms.backup_start_date = (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date) FROM [msdb]..[backupset] b2 
                                   WHERE bms.database_name = b2.database_name AND b2.type = 'D') 
   WHERE sd.name NOT IN ('Pubs','tempdb','Northwind', 'Adventureworks')
```

[Reference](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1800/script-to-check-that-backup-files-still-exist-for-sql-server/)